# PHP: Blowfish Algorithm giving *0 as output

Tags: php, algorithm, blowfish

I am playing around with Blowfish algorithm today. Everything works fine but sometimes my program fails as Blowfish Algo gives `*0` as an output,so whole of the logic after that tumbles down.

[image]

On PHP's official documentation page for `CRYPT` under `changelog` it is mentioned that this issue has been solved in version 5.3.2

```
5.3.2    Fixed Blowfish behaviour on invalid rounds to return "failure" string ("*0" or "*1"), instead of falling back to DES.
```

I am using `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.2` and still facing the same issue. Here is the program:

```
<?php
$password = 'Rajat';
$userpassword = 'Rajat';
echo $password;
echo "\n";
echo "Salt: ";
$salt = substr(uniqid(rand()),0,22);
echo $salt;
echo "\n";
echo "Using Blowfish: ";
$bf = crypt($password,'$2y$10$'.$salt);
echo $bf;
echo "\n";
echo "Starting password checking...\n";
$full_bf_salt = substr($bf,0,29);
$verify_hash = crypt($userpassword,$full_bf_salt);
echo "Verified calculated hash: ".$verify_hash;
if($verify_hash==$bf){
 echo "Password is correct\n";
}else{
 echo "Password is incorrect\n";
}
?>
```

Most of the time,crypt function works as expected but it fails sometimes.Does anyone know why or is there something I have implemented in a wrong way?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions?

Comment: @GergoErdosi: It is not about using a fully baked solution(function),it about understanding the details of how things work.

Comment: i tested it with mine. it worked perfectly. php 5.4.16 / 32bit

Comment: @chathux: how many times did you check it?I tried 20 times in a row then only I got *0 as you see it the picture

Comment: The issue is not "solved" in 5.3.2. What they fixed was the old behavior of silently falling back to DES. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: @Rajat Saxena 100 times programmatically in row.. but as Gergo Erdosi mentioned in the answer the generated salt is less than 22. may be it is the problem. but still worked in my case. after blowfished it gave me something like $2y$10$1295853defc7ea5fe9$$$.lfR78m/IgFZR7IONO52i6AUVPjd80fe. as we can see embedded salt contains $$$ for missing chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the error with your code. You get `*0` as a result when the length of the generated salt is less than 22. In my case the length was 21 characters.

```
Salt: string(21) "6948531853de8c4cd7a85"
Using Blowfish: *0
```

Bcrypt expects a 128 bit salt encoded in a base64 format, resulting in 22 characters of salt. When the salt is not valid, `*0` is returned to indicate that there was an error.

Here is one way to generate the salt properly using [`mcrypt_create_iv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php):

```
$raw_salt_len = 16;
$required_salt_len = 22;

$salt = mcrypt_create_iv($raw_salt_len, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);

$base64_digits = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
$bcrypt64_digits = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

$base64_string = base64_encode($salt);
$salt = strtr(rtrim($base64_string, '='), $base64_digits, $bcrypt64_digits);

if (function_exists('mb_substr')) {
    $salt = mb_substr($salt, 0, $required_salt_len, '8bit');
} else {
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, $required_salt_len);
}
```

I extracted this code from the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library. I highly recommend to study its code. It covers cases when `mcrypt_create_iv()` is not available, etc.